# How to call a batch file from visual studio 2010

Tags: c, file, batch-file, execute

I wrote a code which produces airfoils shapes and evaluate them using an external program as an evaluation tool. I also made a batch file which starts this program execute some batch commands needed for the airfoil shape evaluation and then closes the program....!!

I do several evaluations during each loop. My problem is that i cannot find a way to run the batch file through my code. I have used the two ways showed below but neither of them seems to work in visual studio 2010. I code in C and i get the message that C:/Users/Angelos/Documents/CExperiments/BSplines/run.bat is not an internal command and so on...!

Can you please check it and tell me what am i doing wrong..?

Thank you

```
void XfoilCall()
{
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = ("C:/Users/Angelos/Documents/CExperiments/BSplines/run.bat");
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = ("");
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);


void XfoilCall()
{
system("C:/Users/Angelos/Documents/CExperiments/BSplines/run.bat");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead try this:

```
system("cmd C:/Users/Angelos/Documents/CExperiments/BSplines/run.bat");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your slashes are in the wrong direction (they should be backslashes) and need to be escaped. You also need to launch the command interpreter (`cmd.exe`) to process the batch script.

```
ShExecInfo.lpFile = ("cmd.exe /c C:\\Users\\Angelos\\Documents\\CExperiments\\BSplines\\run.bat");
```